# Can we simply say this regarding the number of elements in the Galois Group?

Tags: galois-theory

Consider a polynomial like $x^4-10x^2+1=0$, which has four distinct roots $\pm \sqrt{2} \pm \sqrt{3}$. The Galois Group  has 4 elements, so the Galois Group is isomorphic to the Klein-4 group.

Now suppose we are working with polynomials with rational coefficients. would it be safe to say that for every radical, there is a plus/minus version so there would always be $2k$ elements, where $k$ is the number of radicals?

For example, the polynomial $x^4-2x^2-1=0$ has a root $\sqrt{1+\sqrt{2}}$ so can we safely say that the other roots will be in the form $\pm \sqrt{1 \pm \sqrt{2}}$? In other words, there are four elements in the Galois group over the rationals?

Answer (score 3):

No, in general you cannot draw such conclusions about the size of the Galois group.

The Galois group $G$ will always (faithfully) permute those $2^k$ zeros (not $2k$, but that was probably a typo). If the polynomial is irreducible then we can conclude that $G$ will act transitively on the set of roots. This implies that $2^k\mid |G|$. But there may be more than $2^k$ permutations in the Galois group, because it is possible that there are non-trivial permutations in $G$ that keep some of the zeros fixed. With non-trivial point-stabilizers the size of the group grows accordingly.

Your latter polynomial
$$
p(x)=x^4-2x^2-1=(x^2-1)^2-2
$$
is a case in point. This polynomial has two real zeros, $\pm\sqrt{1+\sqrt2}$, and two complex zeros $\pm\sqrt{1-\sqrt2}$. The usual complex conjugation maps the real roots to themselves, but swaps the complex ones. 
This is an indication that the Galois group is larger. In this case it is not too difficult to show that $G$ has eight elements, and is isomorphic to the dihedral group $D_4$.

Another way of seeing the difference between your two example polynomials is that in the first case one of the roots (any one will do) will generate the splitting field. Say, if we pick $u=\sqrt2+\sqrt3$. Then $1/u=\sqrt3-\sqrt2$, and it is easy to see that we can write all of $\pm\sqrt2\pm\sqrt3$ in terms of $u$ alone. In other words $\Bbb{Q}(u)$ is the splitting field. This is in sharp contrast to what happens with the other polynomial. If we single out $v=\sqrt{1+\sqrt2}$, then we cannot write the non-real zeros $\pm\sqrt{1-\sqrt2}$ in terms of $v$ alone. The field $\Bbb{Q}(v)$ has only real numbers, and consequently cannot be the splitting field.

One final note. Assume that you can show that $Q(a_1)$, with $a_1$ one of those sign combos, is, indeed, the splitting field. Then it does follow that the Galois group is a group of size $2^k$. Namely, a field automorphism $\sigma$ is fully determined once we know $\sigma(a_1)$. Thus $a_1$ has a trivial point stabilizer inside $G$. Consequently $|G|$ is equal to the number of zeros.

Answer (score 2):

What Jyrki said. In addition, not every radical comes in plus/minus forms. $\root3\of2$ is a zero of $x^3-2$, but $-\root3\of2$ isn't. What's more, most polynomials have roots that can't be expressed as radicals at all, e.g., the roots of $x^5-x-1=0$.